# Create Line Breaks in Data Description

Tags: css, html, line-breaks

I have CSS that is using Data Description to display text on a page.

Code:

***CSS***

```
#nav a:after { 
      text-align:center; 
      content: attr(data-description); 
      display: block;
}
```

***HTML***

```
<li><a data-description="The Thinking Man,The Artist, The Philosopher"  href="#">The Renaissance Man</a></li>
```

What I am having trouble with and would I would like to do is to have each part of the sentence on its on line. In other words

```
The Thinking Man
The Artist
The Philosopher
```

But when I insert a `<br />` it doesn't creat a break it just displays `<br />` in the code. How would I create line breaks in a data description using the following code?

Comment: How about adding some `width`?

Comment: @Vucko - That doesn't work because 1) it throws off the centering of the description underneath the main text. 2) I am still left with `the` on one line when it should be the next line. Needs to be a break.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* add a new line by combining `\A` with `white-space:pre-wrap;`, for example:

```
p:after {
    content:"Line 1\ALine 2";
    white-space:pre-wrap;
}

/* Line 1
 * Line 2 */
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/gdvD7/).

Unfortunately it doesn't seem you can do this using `attr()`.

```
<p data-description="Line 1\ALine 2"></p>
```

```
p:after {
    content:attr(data-description);
    white-space:pre-wrap;
}

/* Line 1\ALine 2 */
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/gdvD7/1/).

What you could do to get around this is to use multiple data-* attributes:

```
<p data-description1="Line 1" data-description2="Line 2"></p>
```

```
p:after {
    content:attr(data-description1) "\A" attr(data-description2);
    white-space:pre-wrap;
}

/* Line 1
 * Line 2 */
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/gdvD7/2/).

I don't know if this is a usable solution to your problem, however.

Comment: Ah yes, look at that. Good answer!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The last solution `<p data-description1="Line 1" data-description2="Line 2"></p>` looks to be the best solution.

Comment: Question: When using ` white-space:pre-wrap;` it works *but* the dropdown now has a ton of space. I cannot get the space to not be there. I tried adding `white-space:normal;` to other CSS but it doesn't work. Thoughts?

Comment: @Lynda you can try `pre` or `pre-line` instead of `pre-wrap`. Unfortunately `\A` relies on the `white-space` property not collapsing white space. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html

Answer (score 1):

The `content` attribute won't ever interpret your Html as markup, so you'll need to go about this another way.

One way would be escaping the newline and setting `white-space: pre;` in your pseudoelement. This value is an abbreviation for 'preserves,' which means the newline will be rendered by the browser.

```
The Thinking Man,\AThe Artist,\AThe Philosopher
```

[**View on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ra6dL/1/)

For more on the white-space property, [refer to the MDN article on it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

For more on escaping new lines in `content`, check out the [CSS2 specs on strings](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings).